Decimals in the psp22 contract
What is the role of decimals in the PSP22 contract ??
as by default Balance data-type will automatically take the number of decimal places that we have set in the chain, so what is the role of decimals data-type in the psp22 contract ?
sharing the link :- openbrush-psp22
